# How to get data in real time in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

It is my first project in vue. I am getting the cart-data from the server. i want to change quantity from the vue. When i click change quantity i.e up arrow and down arrow, change is reflected in the server database. but in UI i have to reload the page to see change which i do not want that.

i want to see the change in without reloading when button is click. and i want to run `TotalCartPrice` method without clicking any button. I mean when i open cart it should be automatically run. what is wrong?

**cart.vue**

```
<template>
    <CartItem v-for="cart in carts" :key="cart.id" :carts="cart" />
</template>
<script>
import CartItem from "../components/cart/cartItem";
export default {
  name: "CartPage",
  components: {
    CartItem
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["carts"])
  },
  created() {},
  methods: {
    TotalCartPrice() {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.carts.length; i++) {
        total += this.carts[i].product.price * this.carts[i].quantity;
      }
      return total;
    }
  }
};
```

**CartItem.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
     <h5>${{ carts.product.price }}</h5>
     <div class="product_count">
        <input
          disabled
          name="qty"
          maxlength="12"
          :value="carts.quantity"
          class="input-text qty"
        />
        <button
          @click="addProduct()"
          class="increase items-count"
          type="button"
        >
          <i class="lnr lnr-chevron-up"></i>
        </button>
        <button
          @click="removeProduct()"
          class="reduced items-count"
          type="button"
        >
          <i class="lnr lnr-chevron-down"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "cartItem",
  props: {
    carts: {
      required: true,
      type: Object
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cartDetail: {
        product: this.carts.product.id,
        quantity: null,
        customer: null,
        checkout: false
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["authUser"])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["addTocart"]),
    addProduct() {
      this.cartDetail.quantity = 1;
      this.cartDetail.customer = this.authUser.id;
      this.addTocart(this.cartDetail);
    },
    removeProduct() {
      this.cartDetail.quantity = -1;
      this.cartDetail.customer = this.authUser.id;
      this.addTocart(this.cartDetail)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Cart.js**

```
const state = {
  carts: []
};
const getters = {
  carts: state => state.carts
};
const actions = {
  async addTocart({ commit }, data) {
    const JsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    const response = await axios.post("/api/v1/cart/view-set/", JsonData);
    return response;
  },
  async cart({ commit }, data) {
    if (data !== "null") {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/v1/cart/cartdetial/${data}`);
      commit("setCarts", response.data);
      return response;
    }
  }
};
const mutations = {
  setCarts: (state, carts) => {
    state.carts = carts;
  }
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Vuex - can you show the relevant part of the Vuex code?

Comment: Search for `socket.io` keyword to listen to the quantity from server. Or you can increase the quantity when the change quantity action finish successfully.

Answer (score 1):

`TotalCartPrice` should be a computed property:

```
    TotalCartPrice: function() {
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.carts.length; i++) {
        total += this.carts[i].product.price * this.carts[i].quantity;
      }
      return total;
    }
```

From the docs on the difference between computed and methods:

> ...computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed. This means as long as message has not changed, multiple access to the reversedMessage computed property will immediately return the previously computed result without having to run the function again.

This way, your cart price will update whenever `this.carts` is updated.

Comment: Thank you this help me for the `TotalCartPrice`. But what might be solution for changing data without reloading in cart, when button is clicked. i have to still reload. as your request i have show vuex code

Comment: You could trigger `cart` from within `addToCart` using `dispatch`: `async addTocart({ commit, dispatch }, data) { const JsonData... dispatch("cart")` so it would fetch the updated items for every POST request. I'm not sure why you're returning `response` in each action though, it's not necessary. Also, why are you passing a `data` argument to `cart`?